# Check for Continuous Time Variable in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe in following format with time and a variable.

```
time     var1
14:01:01 0.36
14:01:02 0.38
14:01:03 0.39
14:01:04 0.39
14:01:05 0.40
14:01:07 0.42
```

What would be the best way to check the continuous time variable if there is any missing points as such "14:01:06" in above case?

Comment: Use `?diff` after converting your time via `as.POSIXct` and check if it's greater than 1 second

Comment: @thelatemail diff(as.POSIXct(df$time))
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: You need to specify a format (and probably a timezone) like  `as.POSIXct(df$time, format="%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")` - R is not a mind reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `diff` after converting your `time` variable to a formal time representation. E.g.:

```
df$missingflag <- c(1, diff(as.POSIXct(df$time, format="%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC"))) > 1
df
#      time var1 missingflag
#1 14:01:01 0.36       FALSE
#2 14:01:02 0.38       FALSE
#3 14:01:03 0.39       FALSE
#4 14:01:04 0.39       FALSE
#5 14:01:05 0.40       FALSE
#6 14:01:07 0.42        TRUE
```